# Can't pip install psutil on Debian (Raspbian)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, psutil

I am trying to install psutil on my Raspbian VM where I am working on the python code. Later I am planning to upload it to pi.

Every time when I try to install psutil, it gives following error.

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ pip3 install psutil
Collecting psutil
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 138, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 75, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 837, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 281, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 147, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6066dac>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

*Here is my pastebin as I can't upload entire error log https://pastebin.com/EyWVmuju*

I did some research and realized I need to install 'python-dev' however it didn't helped.

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.5.3-1).
python3-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: *Name or service not known* Does the VM have access to the Internet? Can you `ping pypi.org`?

Comment: @phd Thanks for pointing it out. It was a network problem. I was using the Virtual Box 'NAT Network' and it seemed like there was no problem with network, I realized that guest network interface have some bugs. I changed it to 'NAT' Network and it was operating correctly. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `python3-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```